# Is there some kind of metacharacter in Regex or Bash that is a wildcard for common separators?

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I mean characters like `- _|/\()[]{}` or/and others I must forget.

A usecase would be, for instance, and assuming this character is ¤ :

`apt-search ¤obs¤`

enabling filtering of results such as `obsolete` `observation`, etc...

Or more generally `X | egrep ¤`.

I guess I don't have the good terminology for it, but I was unable to find results online.

Comment: Which application are you searching an answer for? This question is tagged `bash`, but the in the example of `apt-search ....`, it would actually be `apt-search` doing to regular expression matching.

Comment: @Wieland, Well I'm looking for the most general solution, so it doesn't matter. `apt` was simply an example. Just think of `apt-search obs | grep ¤` or more generally `X | egrep ¤` (or a more efficient way I'm not aware of). I'll modify my answer to reflect the general way.

Comment: `[[:punct:]]+`, though it looks no better than enumerating them ;-). But I think that you better use the `\<` and `\>` (start/end of word "zero-length assertions") which are supported by apt: `apt-cache search '\<obs\>'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regex it is `[] _|/\()[{}-]`, just the whole lot between `[]`. However note that `]` has to be the first (to stop it being interpreted as the close), and `-` has to be first or last (to stop it being interpreted as a range).

Answer (score 0):

Here, you could use the word boundary operators: either the `\b` from `perl` or `\<`, `\>` from `vi` both supported by `apt` and `aptitude`.

That matches at the transition between a word character and a non-word character, a word character being an alphanumeric character or underscore in that case. That wouldn't work for you in that you want to consider `_` as a separator, but note that Debian packages don't have `_` in their name, so that shouldn't be an issue if it's the package name you want to match  against.

To search on package name only:

```
$ aptitude search '~n \bobs\b'
p   obs-api                         - Open Build Service (api)
p   obs-build                       - scripts for building RPM/debian packages f
p   obs-plugins                     - recorder and streamer for live video conte
p   obs-plugins:i386                - recorder and streamer for live video conte
p   obs-plugins-dbgsym              - debug symbols for obs-plugins
p   obs-plugins-dbgsym:i386         - debug symbols for obs-plugins
p   obs-productconverter            - Open Build Service (product definition uti
p   obs-server                      - Open Build Service (server component)
p   obs-studio                      - recorder and streamer for live video conte
p   obs-studio:i386                 - recorder and streamer for live video conte
p   obs-studio-dbgsym               - debug symbols for obs-studio
p   obs-studio-dbgsym:i386          - debug symbols for obs-studio
p   obs-utils                       - Open Build Service (utilities)
v   obs-webui                       -
p   obs-worker                      - Open Build Service (build host component)
```

Because `\b` is a word boundary, it also matches at the start of the subject, even though in that case `obs` is not preceded by a separator character.